# Please wait page on submit Click

Tags: asp.net

I want to redirect my page to wait page on click of submit button till transaction is getting processed.please help me with the code.
I m using C# language.

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("your page.aspx");

Or

Server.Transfert("");
```

Here you find an sample very easy based on ajax scripting : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9877/Building-a-Better-Wait-Page

Comment: On Submit button it is getting redirected to new page.Now on Click of Submit button I am redirecting it to WaitPage...to show Please wait screen till transaction is getting processed...For that ,On page load of WaitPage i have added   code of Submit button..But Please wait msg on page is not getting displayed as it is redirecting to new page in pageload() .How I can show Please wait mesaage?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look here:

http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/implementing-waiting-pages-in-asp.net/

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/thread299-please-wait-page.aspx

http://maheshkumar.wordpress.com/2005/03/14/wait-page-in-asp-net/